# Как присвоить всем документам заданные неймспейсы в VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespace

У меня в учебном солюшене примено 10 проектов, в каждом из них примерно 5-10 документов. Все они так или иначе друг к другу подключаются.
Например:

```
using BasicLibrary.Collections;
using ConsoleEngine;
using static ConsoleEngine.StaticMethods;
using ConsoleSymbolsEngine;
using static ConsoleSymbolsEngine.StaticMethods;
using DrawingLibrary;
using ConsoleDrawing;
using static ConsoleDrawing.StaticMethods;
using SymbolsPictures;
using SymbolsEngine;
using ConsoleSymbolsDrawingEngine;
using static ConsoleSymbolsDrawingEngine.StaticMethods;
```

Для каждого проекта я хочу, чтобы в каждом его документе у меня были заданные неймспейсы. Я не хочу вручную менять нейспейсы во всех проектах, во-первых, потому что я меняю их часто, во-вторых, потому что я могу пропустить какой-либо из документов (они ещё по папкам раскиданы). Ну и это долго.
Я бы хотел команду, которая присвоит всем .cs документам проекта заданные подключения библиотек.
Желательно, с дополнительным отступом и без повторений.
Существует ли такая? Я искал, но не нашёл.
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Зачем вам в каждом файле писать одинаковые `namespace`, если есть такая штука, как [глобальные пространства имен](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.52.php) (c#10) ? И да, как по мне, если у вас куча `namespace`, то у вас проблема в архитектуре проекта.

Comment: Попробуйте [NamespaceFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Действительно, вы правы, на моём .NET стеке нет С# 10. Ну что ж, буду терпеть.
А почему если у меня куча namespace, то у есть проблема в архитектуре проекта?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не помог(

Comment: @VladisS Обычно, когда указывается много namespace, это означает, что объект имеет много зависимостей и/или он берет много на себя ответственности. Помним да, класс должен отвечать за что-то одно (SRP), то есть, если у вас вон рисовалка картинок и вывод картинок - это два разных класса, а не один. Также лишние namespace убираются такими вещами как простое наследование, где у вас одни класс реализует конкретную (общую) логику, а другие просто наследуются от него и реализуют уже что-то другое. Ну а если у вас куча namespace, то скорей всего у вас в классе каша, но без кода конкретней не сказать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, было полезно.